Copulas: obtaining uniform marginal distribution via pseudo observation or via CDF?
I'm studying copulas for a Time Series Analysis exam, and, to practice, our professor gave us an exercise on financial data.
One point of the exercise is to fit an elliptical copula to estimate the correlation between the excess returns of two assets, and now I have some questions.
Should I fit the best elliptical copula (so gaussian or t) using the vinecopula package? Otherwise, how should I know the parameters of the copulas?
To fit the copula, I need to transform the data into their uniform distributions right?
I read that, to do so, there are two approaches:

Calculating the pseudo-observations using the pobs() function
If I know the marginal distributions (in my example I tried to find the best distribution using the fitdistrplus package), using the CDFs to obtain the uniform distribution (not completely sure about this point)

I tried both approaches and they returns different copulas, which makes sense. But the main problem is that when I make the scatterplot of the two marginal uniform distributions I got a bizarre plot for the one obtained using the CDFs.
Here's the one using the cdf:

Here's the one using the pseudo-observations:

Thank you very much in advance

the uniform scatter doesn't look bizarre. it's rather typical for financial asset returns. also, to fit copula you don't necessarily need to fit to uniforms, there are other techniques for ellipticals

Thank you very much for the answer. So, if the plot makes sense, why is it so different from the pseudo observations one? Which approach should I use?

difference between observed and simulated is usually due to poor fit of the copula. perhaps, your copula is not for this dataset
